# Record Terminal output?

Tags: terminal, logging, macos

Im using a cool program in terminal but it's pre-compiled... Luckily all I need is the output of this system, but the way I need it is tricky... I need it to run normally but output the last line of text in the window to a text file. I jabs been looking around but people only make it so that I can log the whole thing, not just the last line.

it is a compiled unix executable that can't be run with something like that because it needs to keep running and won't stop until stopped, and that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the `tail` command](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tail.1.html) to only capture the last `n` lines of a file or a stream. For example, to run `./myProgram` but only display the last line of output:

```
./myProgram | tail -n 1
```

This pipes (`|`) the output of your program into the input of `tail`, which discards everything except the last `n` lines.

To save that output to a file instead, you can redirect (`>`) `tail`'s output to a file:

```
./myProgram | tail -n 1 > out.txt
```

Comment: it is a compiled unix executable that can't be run with something like that because it needs to keep running and won't stop until stopped, and that didn't work

Comment: @TrevorRudolph: That is how you would run a compiled linux executable, in normal cases. Can you please include more information in your question about either the software you're running or the partial solution you had?

Comment: I'm on mac and I'm running an executable that outputs data from the kinect, it only show new users in the terminal window though

Answer (score 2):

Use [`tail`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tail) to get only the last line:

```
cool-program | tail -n 1 > text-file
```

If `cool-program` runs (and outputs) forever, redirect *its* output and tail then:

```
cool-program > log
# Later, when you're interested in the current last line:
tail -n 1 log
```

Comment: it is a compiled unix executable that can't be run with something like that because it needs to keep running and won't stop until stopped, and that didn't work

Comment: @Trevor It's completely irrelevant whether the executable is compiled or interpreted. What do you mean "with something like that?" All UNIX programs are executed by some variant of `execve`, and the above shell  command does call `execve`. If the program runs forever ("won't stop until stopped"), how can you ever determine what is the last line? Updated the answer with a way to find out the current last line.

Comment: i understand now!!!! you see by the last line i meant the current line of text showing in the terminal

Comment: but i need it to keep pumping out the current line so the file keeps changing

Comment: @Trevor Rudolph That's exactly what the second part in the updated answer does.